# c# saving an image of a control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

what is the best way to save an image of a  control?

currently i am doing this:

```
        chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
```

how would i then prompt the user with a windowsavedialogue and save the BMP to a specific location?

if this is not the best way to do this please suggest a different way

Comment: @richard: I believe MemoryStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Daok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13913/daok) has a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180330/c-save-dialog-box/180332#180332) for this.

Adapting Daok's code to change the extension Filter gives you this

```
chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog(); 
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments; 
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Your extension here (*.bmp)|*.*" ; 
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1; 

if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
        bm.Save (saveFileDialog1.FileName);//Do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prompt them with a `SaveFileDialog` that would allow them to choose the path and file name and file type where they want to save the file.

Then you just need to write the bmp to a file

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
// ... add your dialog options
DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog(owner);

if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    bm.Save(dlg.FileName);
}
```