# Using SaveFileDialog in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm basically just trying to get a file path to save a file to but my SaveFileObject won't let me access the SelectedPath. I've checked the other forums and can't figure out why it won' tlet me, here's my code;

```
SaveFileDialog filePath = new SaveFileDialog();
 DialogResult result = filePath.ShowDialog();


     if (result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         string folderPath = filePath.;
     }
```

It'll let me select filePath.ShowDialog again and filePath.ToString etc... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you saying it won't let you do folderPath = filePath.FileName;

Comment: You went wrong when you found that your guess was wrong, and chose not to read the documentation to find out what the property is called.

Comment: It won't let me write "string folderPath = filePath.SelectedPath" to acccess the file path selected by the user after filePath.ShowDialog()

Comment: filePath.FileName will return file exact path.

Comment: Ok, I see... I think I've been staring at my computer for too long

Comment: Well now you know: If Intellisense says the property you want doesn't exist, your memory is more likely to be faulty than Intellisense's memory (except in recent versions of MSSQLMS, where you're lucky if Intellisense works at all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving file using SaveFileDialog in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136254/saving-file-using-savefiledialog-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want the file name from the FileName property from your SaveFileDialog. That will give you the full path and file name for the file your user wants to save.

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
DialogResult result = saveDialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    String fileName = saveDialog.FileName;
    //your code to save the file;
}
```

Although, since `.ShowDialog()` returns a DialogResult, you can use it directly in the if to spare one line of code (yup! I'm greedy)