# How to export to excel in windows app C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, export-to-excel

I am new in Windows Application development, Trying to write code for exporting dataset to excel. I have read several examples on the internet regarding this but all are exporting the file to a location. I want to export file like in web (as an open asking to save as file).
Below is my code for the web app, what changes we need to run it on a window?

```
DataGridView grid_records = new DataGridView();
grid_records.DataSource = dset;
//grid_records.DataBind();

Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = "";
string FileName = "UIDAI" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
grid_records.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
grid_records.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
grid_records.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
//Response.End();

Response.Flush();
Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: .net web framework is different from desktop applications. You don't need to use `Response` class, you just need to use fileSaveDialog for saving at a desired location and `Process` class to open the file if the fileReader is available in the system i.e. PDF reader, Excel etc.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid , can you refer any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for so many hints , Below is my final code after converting to window app 
hope it will help others

```
   private void btn_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
            savefile.FileName = "Response.xls";
            savefile.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName))
                    //    sw.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName);
                    for (int i = 0; i < dset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        wr.Write(dset.Tables[0].Columns[i].ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
                    }

                    wr.WriteLine();

                    //write rows to excel file
                    for (int i = 0; i < (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (dset.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] != null)
                            {
                                wr.Write(Convert.ToString(dset.Tables[0].Rows[i][j]) + "\t");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wr.Write("\t");
                            }
                        }
                        //go to next line
                        wr.WriteLine();
                    }
                    //close file
                    wr.Close();
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Data saved in Excel format at location "+ savefile.FileName , "Successfully Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this,"Zero record to export , perform a operation first","Can't export file",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, v1.PrintExceptionDetails(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            el.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will tell you [How to export Dataset to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp), if you see the 2nd answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182029/how-to-export-datagridview-data-instantly-to-excel-on-button-click), you'll find out how would you allow user to save the document at any location in their pc. You can open `Excel` file [by following this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)

Always search before asking a question because everything is available here whatever you'd asked.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

While searching for windows desktop application related answers use keywords "Winforms","C#".

You need to select a file using `SaveFileDialog` class and use `FileStream` to write content to it.

You can find detailed samples [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx), [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/savefiledialog-in-C-Sharp/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136254/saving-file-using-savefiledialog-in-c-sharp/5136341).