# SaveFileDialog cannot find desktop folder path

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I'm using `SavefileDialog` in C#. However, my `SavefileDialog` can't find the desktop folder path.

This is my code:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog(this);

if( result == DialogResult.OK) {
    // do something
}
```

Once `SaveFileDialog` is started, this error pops up:

> Error: 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop' refers to a location that is unavailable.

Why does the error pop up and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Please provide more details/code for anyone here to provide useful response. Along with the code, you also should mention the OS version you have.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931123/336511

Comment: What kind of app is this? A winforms app? A service? It seems like it is running as the system user which does not have a desktop directory.

Comment: Well, have you checked to make sure that the path `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` actually exists? Because the desktop path doesn't look like this normally.

Answer (score 4):

To make `SaveFileDialog` open on particular directory, use `InitialDirectory`:

```
 SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
 sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
 DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog(this);
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     // do something
 }
```

As for your error, please provide more details or at least the whole code of the method.