# How can I save the XML contents of an XDocument as an .xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, io, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument class with the XML contents already made. I basically want to open a SaveFileDialog, have the user choose a folder (not a file) in which to save the contents as an .xml file.

I'm having some difficulty doing so:

a) How can I use the SaveFileDialog to prompt the user to select a folder? I've only been able to use it to get a user to select a file.

b) How do I extract the chosen path from SaveFileDialog?

c) Once I have the path, how can I save the contents of the XDocument? There's a method called Save that requires a Stream - how do I build the stream using the path? (This might be a basic question, I have almost no IO experience)

Comment: You are asking too many things in the same question. Split this into two questions. One regarding SaveFileDialog and one for saving the XDocument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) You don't want to select a Folder, but a file name (Save**File**Dialog)

b) SaveFileDialog.FileName

c) Look at different overloads : you have XDocument.Save(string fileName). No need to have a stream, you can have a fileName (oh, you got it in SaveFileDialog)

**EDIT** : you mean user can't change the name of the file ?
then

a) FolderBrowserDialog

b) FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath

c) XDocument.Save(FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + THENAMEOFYOURFILETHATUSERCANTCHANGE)

(**EDIT 2** : Path.Combine is more elegant in c) ).

Answer (score 3):

A & B (sample code from duplicate question):

- [C# Save Dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180330/c-sharp-save-dialog-box)

C (minimum code to save `XDocument`):

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();
document.Add(new XElement("my_root"));
// Save(): there are 6 overloads; the 2nd one takes a path
document.Save(filePathFromSaveDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added SaveFileDialog to your form and signed to FileOk event (can be done though SaveFileDialog's properties), then following code should work for your:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When user clicks button, show the dialog.
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Get file name.
    string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    // Write to the file name selected.
    xDocumentYouHave.Save(name);
}
```