# Export DataGrid to Excel C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagrid

I'm looking for how to export a datagrid (not datagridview) to Excel. I am working on VS 2003 Winform. I'm looking on the net, but without result, and I find that solutions are just about Datagridview VS 2010 (asp).

This is what I have so far:

```
lblMessage.Text = ""; 
// Export all the details 
try 
{ 
    // Get the datatable to export 
    DataTable dtEmployee = dsEmployee.Tables["Employee"].Copy(); 
    // Export all the details to Excel 
    RKLib.ExportData.Export objExport = new RKLib.ExportData.Export("Win");
    objExport.ExportDetails(dtEmployee, Export.ExportFormat.Excel, "C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls");
    lblMessage.Text = "Successfully exported to C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls";
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{ 
    lblMessage.Text = Ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: do you want to do it by code ?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373925/c-sharp-winforms-app-export-dataset-to-excel?rq=1

Comment: yes i want to do it by code  :)

Comment: this code in this link is not for datagrid but datagridview :s

Answer (score 0):

Reading grid (pseudo-code):

```
 // Here Interop to Excel Application, save empty workbook (xls file)
 // Here connect to the create workbook using ACE
 for (int i = 0; i < grid.rows.count; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < grid.columns.count; j++)
     {
         // here use one of the methods described in this link to write data 
         // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023
         //   ----->  grid.Item(i, j) = excel cell  <--------
     }
 }
```

See this:

[Writing to excel using OleDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807362/writing-to-excel-using-oledb)

Also this:

Associate a cell in the grid to a cell in `Excel` e.g. A1, D7, etc.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302094

Comment: This is not true. Grid has property `Item` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
 So this code should do it

Comment: yes but i can't  write this : datagrid1.rows OR datagrid1.Columns

Comment: That was a pseudo code as it pointed. Your grid must be attached to a `DataSource`, which most likely is a `DataTable`. So, what you do is: `DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid.Datasource`. And then, on a `dt`, go and iterate every row and column.

Comment: i have this code i don't know how to add a DialogBox to Save the file in specific place .please help  :

Comment: // Export all the details
   try
   {   
    // Get the datatable to export   
    DataTable dt = dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Copy();
    dsSelectionListeDiffere = FrmFonctionPrincipale.getListeDifferesParClient(1);
    // Export all the details to Excel

    RKLib.ExportData.Export objExport = new RKLib.ExportData.Export("Win");    
    objExport.ExportDetails(dt, Export.ExportFormat.Excel, "C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls");
    MessageBox.Show("Exporté Avec Succès dans  C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls");
   }
   catch(Exception Ex)
   {
  MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
//lblMessage.Text = Ex.Message;
   }

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180330/c-sharp-save-dialog-box>
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180330/c-sharp-save-dialog-box>